# Fortify Sourceanalyzer - Missing java class when analyzing XWiki

Tags: maven-2, fortify, xwiki

The missing class is `com.xpn.xwiki.test.AbstractXWikiComponentTestCase`. This is the only class that cannot be resolved. I have run:

> mvn package

Then I have tried to build with sourceanalyzer and this is the only class that cannot be found. I do not understand why mvn package would not have gotten this for me.

Answer (score 4):

If you're getting missed dependencies when building with the Fortify SCA Maven2 plugin, you should try the "install" goal instead of the "package" goal.

"install" puts the dependencies into your repository.  The Fortify SCA Maven2 Plugin looks in the repository for dependencies.

I hope this helps! Please let us know.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're missing a jar. did you see any lines earlier in the build attempting to download dependencies?

The XWiki jars aren't hosted on central, but you can add the XWiki repository to your pom using configuration like this:

```
<repositories>
  <repository>
    <id>xwiki-releases</id>
    <name>XWiki Maven2 Remote Repository for Releases</name>
    <url>http://maven.xwiki.org/releases</url>
    <releases>
      <enabled>true</enabled>
    </releases>
    <snapshots>
      <enabled>false</enabled>
    </snapshots>
  </repository>
</repositories>
```

Once that configuration is added, Maven should download all the required dependencies. If it still doesn't, you can explicitly add the missing dependency to your POM:

```
<dependencies>
  ...
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.xwiki.platform</groupId>
    <artifactId>xwiki-core-shared-tests</artifactId>
    <version>??</version>
    <scope>test<!--assume this is just for tests, if not omit the scope declaration--></scope>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```